# How to create a header that changes as you scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a navigation bar that changes as the page is scrolled down similar to the one they have on [techcrunch.com](http://techcrunch.com)

I don't only want to make a sticky header that stays on top, I know how to do that in CSS. But I also want to change its height and the styling of objects nested inside it after scrolling to a certain point.

I have made some research already and most people say it should be done using a .scroll function or something like that in jQuery, but I didn't find a full explanation on how to do it. I'm not very familiar with jQuery or Javascript to be honest.

***All the answers I found for similar questions will not allow me to edit or change the nested content within the header, only change the styling of the header itself.***
I'd be grateful if someone can explain the process for me in some details.
I really want to learn how can to do it, not just copying some code and pasting it into my website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a generic solution.

This involves having multiple headers (which can have totally different content inside) from which you selectively display one depending on the scroll position. Each header element will have a `data-visible-range` attribute that defines the min and max scroll positions when it should be displayed.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/cydfh2s6/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="header header-1" data-visible-range="0-100">Header 1</div>
<div class="header header-2" data-visible-range="101-500">Header 2</div>
<div class="header header-3" data-visible-range="501-">Header 3</div>
<div class="body">BODY</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.header-1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block; /* header 1 is visible by default */
}
.header-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
.header-3 {
    background-color: green;
}
.body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 2000px;   
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var headerToDisplay = false;
    $('.header[data-visible-range]').each(function() {
        var range = $(this).data('visible-range').split('-');
        range[0] = range[0] ? parseInt(range[0], 10) : 0;
        range[1] = range[1] ? parseInt(range[1], 10) : $(document).height();
        if(scrollTop >= range[0] && scrollTop <= range[1]) {
            headerToDisplay = $(this);
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(headerToDisplay && !headerToDisplay.is(':visible')) {
        $('.header[data-visible-range]').hide();
        headerToDisplay.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: It works like magic! Having 2 separate header will actually make things much easier for me when I change the content inside them. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 6):

In this example i am adding class on scroll

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/twn3gs75/

> hear we can listen scroll event like click,so when you scroll it
>   will go in **`$(window).scroll(function() { ----Call----  });`** Now in this
>   function(){} will check how much it will scrolled 1 or 2 or 3 ... etc
>   so depending upon that will apply condition in my code i checked if
>   user scrolled > 1 then apply css.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

Comment: That's a very simple technique that actually works very well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh okay! I'm new here :D
The first answer was much closer to what I'm looking for tbh. Unfortunately it seems like I can only accept 1 answer, but I do appreciate your help so much. Thanks again! :)

Comment: This is most simple than the solution of the top of this page, but is more efficiently with CSS and 3 lines of javascript. Thank you.